# Flask 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, forms, flask, post, get

after click subimit button I have problem like in title, the problem start showing when I separated routes from app to views, when I go to localhost:5000/register/ all is good but when I fill the form and click submit then I have problem 405

app.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,abort
app = Flask(__name__)
import views

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=views.index)
app.add_url_rule('/login/', view_func=views.login)
app.add_url_rule('/register/', view_func=views.register)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

views.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,abort
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/register/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        req = request.form
        email = req.get("email")
        password = req["password"]
        phonenumber = request.form["phonenumber"]
        if email == "" or password == "" or phonenumber=="":
            feedback="Please fill the form"
            alert = "fail"
        else:
            feedback="Account created!"
            alert = "good"
        return render_template('register.html',feedback=feedback,alert=alert)
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("CIAO")
    return render_template('base.html')
```

and form

```
<form class="" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('register') }}">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" minlength="8">
    <input type="tel" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Numer Telefonu" minlength="8" maxlength="9">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask is not finding the POST method handler for the `/register/` endpoint. You're mixing `add_url_rule` and `@route`. You just need the former if you want pluggable views.

I would recommend using the MethodView approach here. Have a separate class for each template and define the `get()` and `post()` methods within that.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from views import Register, Login, Index

app = Flask(__name__)

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=Index.as_view("index"))
app.add_url_rule('/login/', view_func=Login.as_view("login"))
app.add_url_rule('/register/', view_func=Register.as_view("register"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

views.py:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,abort
from flask.views import MethodView


class Register(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return render_template('register.html')

    def post(self):
        req = request.form
        email = req.get("email")
        password = req["password"]
        phonenumber = request.form["phonenumber"]
        if email == "" or password == "" or phonenumber == "":
            feedback = "Please fill the form"
            alert = "fail"
        else:
            feedback = "Account created!"
            alert = "good"
        return render_template('register.html', feedback=feedback, alert=alert)


class Index(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        print("CIAO")
        return render_template('index.html')


class Login(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return render_template('login.html')
```