# How to solve 405 Method Not Allowed (flask)

Tags: python, flask

I'm keep getting the 405 error, I've changed my code following the other related posts but still not working.

routes.py

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, flash, url_for, abort, request
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from flask import Flask
import views.model as mod
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    mod.check_database_init()
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/login',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
    
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        print("post")
        name = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        print(name, password)
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")


@app.route('/register', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")
```

login.html

```html
{% include "header.html" %}


<title>Login</title>

<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "username" name="username" required>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type = "password" placeholder="password" name = "password" required>
    <input type="submit">

    <p>
        Don't have an acoount? <a href="/register">Click me</a> to create a new account
    </p>
</form>

<a href="/">Back to homepage </a>
```

I tried this method, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62464826/13239458, it works but I don't know what went wrong in the code above.

server.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
import views.routes as rou
import views.database as db


app = Flask(__name__)


app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=rou.index)
app.add_url_rule('/login', view_func=rou.login)
app.add_url_rule('/register', view_func=rou.register)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug = True)
```

**UPDATE**

I just change method type into GET (in login.html) and there will be no error and I can see the input from the console, so I think the login method cannot accept the POST method but I have no idea why is that.

Comment: Getting 405 when doing what ?

Comment: when I click submit after entering the username and the password

Comment: You didn’t include your actual views; you need to implement a post method for the login route.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just find out the issue, I created 2 app instances, I move the instantiation into another file then import it, everything works!

Comment: You might want to either provide a better answer, if you think it is useful for others, or delete the question if you feel it was just a "duh" mistake that no one can learn from.  I do not understand what you are saying the solution was.

Answer (score -2):

You have not included:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

in the end of routes.py

Comment: sorry, I have a server.py, i will post that code